# How to handle C++ exceptions when calling functions from Lua?

Tags: c++, exception, lua

I have a working C++ function that I am able to call from Lua. To demonstrate my problem here is an example:

```
int PushHello(lua_State *L){
    string str("Hello");
    lua_pushlstring(L, str.data(), str.length());
    return 1;
}
```

Note: I know I don't have to use string variable there, but it is there to demonstrate the problem.

Here are my two problems:

1. When I call this function from Lua string constructor may throw an exception. Is that a problem? Will Lua handle it and unwind the Lua stack properly? I don't think so. How can I solve that? Do I need to add `try/catch` around all such code and convert the exception to lua_error? Is not there a better solution?
2. Another problem that I have probably solved by compiling Lua as C++ is when `lua_pushlstring()` calls `lua_error()` string destructor would not be called if longjmp was used. Is the problem solved by compiling as C++ and throwing exceptions instead of using longjmp?

To clarify, possible solution I can see to problem 1 would be this:

```
int PushHello(lua_State *L){
    string str;
    try{
        str.assign("Hello");
    catch(exception &e){
        luaL_error(L, e.what());
    }
    lua_pushlstring(L, str.data(), str.length());
    return 1;
}
```

But that is very ugly and error prone as `try/catch` would need to be added to many places. It could be done as a macro and put around every command that can throw, but that would not be much nicer.

Comment: @Blaho I think this stack-exchange [proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/11464/code-review?referrer=aWNm_PdciyFqjFW8CUacGw2 "code review") might be of interest to you. If it is show your support and help get it into beta! :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I have found a reasonable solution. The question is whether it is correct. Instead of exporting (or calling via lua_cpcall) the original function `int PushHello(lua_State *L)` a wrapper `int SafeFunction<PushHello>(lua_State *L)` is exported/called. The wrapper looks like:

```
template<lua_CFunction func>
int SafeFunction(lua_State *L){
    int result = 0;
    try{
        result = func(L);
    }
    // transform exception with description into lua_error
    catch(exception &e){
        luaL_error(L, e.what());
    }
    // rethrow lua error - C++ Lua throws lua_longjmp*
    catch(lua_longjmp*){
        throw;
    }
    // any other exception as lua_error with no description
    catch(...){
        luaL_error(L, "Unknown error");
    }

    return result;
}
```

What do you think about it? Do you see any problems?

Comment: You should not call _luaL_error_ from the catch block. That will leak the exception object. You should push the error message in the stack, and call _lua_error_ later. Something along [these lines](https://github.com/ignacio/LuaCppBridge51/blob/master/lcbBaseObject.h#L245).

Comment: @Ignacio: I don't understand how the exception object could be leaked. It should be safe to throw an exception from `catch` block. I have compiled Lua as C++.

Comment: Sorry. Just seen your comment. You're right. Since you have Lua compiled as C++, luaL_error will throw, so no objects leak. But if you have Lua compiled as C, luaL_error will longjmp, so the exception you have catched won't be destroyed (among other things).

Comment: I have posted an enhanced version of that template function.

Answer (score 4):

**Juraj Blaho**'s answer is great. It has however a drawback: for each function you export with `int SafeFunction<PushHello>(lua_State *L)`, the compiler will generate a copy of *all* code from the template, just as if it was a macro. When numerous small functions are exported, this will be a waste of footprint.

You can easily avoid the problem by defining a common `static` function performing all the job, and the `template` function just calls that common function:

```
static int SafeFunctionCommon(lua_State *L, lua_CFunction func){
    int result = 0;
    try{
        result = func(L);
    }
    // transform exception with description into lua_error
    catch(exception &e){
        luaL_error(L, e.what());
    }
    // rethrow lua error - C++ Lua throws lua_longjmp*
    catch(lua_longjmp*){
        throw;
    }
    // any other exception as lua_error with no description
    catch(...){
        luaL_error(L, "Unknown error");
    }

    return result;
}

template<lua_CFunction func>
int SafeFunction(lua_State *L){
    return SafeFunctionCommon(L, func);
}
```

Comment: Where does the lua_longjmp* come from? Attempting to implement your try/catch, but lua_longjmp is not defined anywhere I can find

Comment: @MintyAnt `lua_longjmp` is an internal structure defined in [`ldo.c`](https://github.com/lua/lua/blob/5.2.4/src/ldo.c#L76) (LUA 5.2.4).

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't use lua_error to denote an error occuring outside of lua functionality. lua_error would be used if you are adding additional lua functions that can be invoke within the bounds of lua. Then lua_error would be appropriate if an error occurs while executing that function.

Also this is a duplicate of [Stack unwinding in C++ when using Lua](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4005865/stack-unwinding-in-c-when-using-lua)

**Edit**

If you are worried about the string destructor being called why not do this:

```
try
{
    string str("Hello");
    lua_pushlstring(L, str.data(), str.length());
}
catch (exception& e)
{
     luaL_error(L, e.what());
}
```

I realize this is a subtle change to what you suggested but there is a difference. If an exception is thrown anything on the stack within the `try{}` will destruct. Just ensure that anything you want to destruct is within that try.

Comment: I don't think it is a duplicate. I probably have no problems with C++ stack unwind. The problem is if an exception is thrown, will Lua catch it and unwind its stack correctly? And as I said the function IS called from Lua. I will clarify that in my question.

Comment: @Juraj you are correct, you did say it would be called within a lua script itself. I misread. I however, still think the other question answers your question. It recommends using Luabind for any exceptions that would be thrown. Lua will then handle that exception and unwind correctly. I think the main difference is you are asking if the Lua stack itself will unwind correctly as opposed to the stack of the current function. According to the answer given yes lua will catch it if you use luabind

Comment: Yes, that is a solution, but I don't want to use LuaBind.

Answer (score 1):

Lua will not catch the C++ exception.  If you do not catch it, it will be passed up the call stack until it is either caught by some other block of code or causes the program to crash (unhandled exception).  If the functions you expose to Lua call functions that can throw exceptions, you should handle them in that function.

Comment: I know that (even that it is not exactly true when Lua is compiled as C++), but the problem is how can I catch that exceptions nicely?

Comment: True (I was assuming you were using Lua as a script to call a function written in your C++ code - that is, not actually compiling your Lua code).  I would catch all the known possible exceptions that can be thrown from the functions you call (e.g. if a function can throw an OutOfBoundsException and you can handle it gracefully, catch it), and use `catch (...)` to catch everything else and exit the function gracefully (perform any needed cleanup, etc).  EDIT:  Basically, I always treat any function I expose to a scripting language as a `nothrow` function.

Comment: The problem is, that the lua_error also emits an exception, so you cannot catch(...).

Comment: I would not use lua_error to push exceptions from C++ into Lua.  I prefer to handle the exceptions in the area they are created whenever possible.

Answer (score 0):

If you compile Lua as C++, then they will use C++ exceptions as errors, whereas if you compile as C then they will use longjmp/setjmp. This basically means that there's no big deal throwing such an exception.

Comment: The problem is not throwing, but catching. When a C++ code (like the string constructor) throws an exception, how will Lua handle this? What do I get for an error message?