# C++ : How to pass function pointer, stored in a local variable, as a template parameter

Tags: c++, templates, pointers, callback

```
using namespace std;

float test1(float i){
    return i * i;
}

int test2(int i){
    return i+9;
}

struct Wrapper{

    typedef void (*wrapper_type)(int);

    template<class R, class A>
    void wrap(string name,R (*fn) (A) ){
        wrapper_type f_ = &Wrapper::wrapper1<R,A,fn>;
        // in the real program, f_ would be passed in an array to some c library
        wrappers[name] = f_;
    }

    void run(int i){
        map<string,wrapper_type>::iterator it, end = wrappers.end();
        for(it=wrappers.begin();it!=end;it++){
            wrapper_type wt = (*it).second;
            (*wt)(i);
        }
    }

    template<class R, class A, R (*fn) (A)>
    static void wrapper1(int mul){
        //do something
        A arg = mul;
        R result = (*fn)( arg );
        cout << "Result: " << result << endl;
    }

    map<string,wrapper_type> wrappers;

};

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    Wrapper w;
    w.wrap("test1",&test1);
    w.wrap("test2",&test2);
    w.run(89);
    return 0;
}
```

Here's the g++ error:

```
main.cpp:31: error: ‘fn’ is not a valid template argument for type ‘float (*)(float)’ because function ‘fn’ has not external linkage
```

From what i understand, the problem is that a local variable has no linkage; thus it can not be used as a template parameter.

So, i wanted to know if there's a way to get around this problem or another technique to accomplish the same ?

Thanks.

Edit 1:

I totally understand that I can't pass a value that can not be determined at compile time as a template paramter. What i'm asking is - is there a better way to do this? Right now the solution that works for me is :

```
template<class R, class A,R (*fn) (A)>
void wrap(string name){
    wrapper_type f_ = &Wrapper::wrapper1<R,A,fn>;
    // in the real program, f_ would be passed in an array to sm c library
    wrappers[name] = f_;
}
```

and called as :

```
w.wrap<float, float, &test1>("test1");
w.wrap<int, int, &test2>("test2");
```

But here I've to pass argument-type during wrapping. Is there someway to avoid this ?

EDIT 2:

Just to clarify or add more info: The interface I want to present to the user has to be similar to LuaBind or Boost.Python i.e. Wrapper.wrap("test1",&test1); should be sufficient.

Comment: When do you know which function that pointer points to - at runtime or at compile time?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Template parameters must be known at compile time, so you'll have to redesign your code taking this into account.

Edit: for your updated question use Boost function_traits.

```
template<R (*fn) (A)>
void wrap(string name){
    wrapper_type f_ = &Wrapper::wrapper1<function_traits<A>::result_type, function_traits<A>::arg1_type,fn>;
    // in the real program, f_ would be passed in an array to sm c library
    wrappers[name] = f_;
}
```

Comment: I understand that paramters must be known at compile-time. Please check the updated question. Thanks.

Comment: In your revised code, wouldn't we also need to add class A, class R as template parameters ? Then this'll become exactly same as the my  current solution (Edit 1)

Comment: @Code freak, right.  But seeing your Edit 2, I'm now confused.  Do you need to have the function pointer as a template parameter or not?  If no, it is easy with function_traits.  If yes, I'll have to think again about it.

Answer (score 1):

what about encapsulating your "test*" functions in classes sharing a common interface and then passing the classes into the templates?

Comment: Yes that works but i would prefer something like boot.python or lu.bind i.e. Wrapper.wrap("func1",&func); Is that possible ?  Thanks

Comment: the only way I see to do so, is not using templates... but this could be only I...

Answer (score 1):

How about using a set of classes with a same named static member function

```
struct FirstAlternative {
    static void DoStuff();
};

struct SecondAlternative {
    static void DoStuff();
};

template<class R, class A, class Alternative>
void wrap(string name) (A) ){
    wrapper_type f_ = &Wrapper::wrapper1<R,A,&Alternative::DoStuff>;
    wrappers[name] = f_;
}
```

and then pass `class Alternative` as a parameter into that template from the call site?

Comment: You proposition is similar to that of sergio. Please check the comment there. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to pass function pointers stored in a variable as a template arguments. Even when the variable is constant and known at compile time. But it is possible to pass a function pointer *literal*:

```
void foo() {
}

typedef void (FunctionPtr*)();

template<FunctionPtr F>
void wrap() {
    F();
}
```

and then call:

```
wrap<&foo>();
```

I have solved similar problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4615890/how-to-handle-c-exceptions-when-calling-functions-from-lua).

Comment: I tried this too, but in this, the return type and the type of paramter also needs to be passed as template paramter. Want to find a way to avoid this. Thanks for the comment though :)

Answer (score 0):

The address of a function is not known during compile time (only later at link time), and template parameters must be known at compile time.

The way around this is exactly what you have done in your first wrap function: Make it a function parameter.