# local variable as non-type template argument

Tags: c++, templates, local, non-type

I want to do something like the following:

```
Example(&Class::MemberFunction, this));

//...

template<class T_CLASS>
inline static void Example(void (T_CLASS::*MemberFunctionPointer)(), T_CLASS* InstancePointer)
{
  SomeClass<T_CLASS>::Bind<MemberFunctionPointer>(InstancePointer);
}
```

But I get the error: *template parameter 'T_MEMBER_FUNCTION' : 'MemberFunctionPointer' : a local variable cannot be used as a non-type argument*

Any solutions for this problem? I want to provide an easier way to call "Bind"

Thanks, Mirco

//edit:

I want MemberFunctionPointer to be a non-type template parameter because in "Bind" I again need it as a template argument. 
As you wrote in your answers, in my case MemberFunctionPointer is a variable and its value is unknown at compile time. But MemberFunctionPointer always points to the same function. Is there a way to for example make it constant so that the compiler knows it at compile time?

Comment: Please look at this very similar question http://stackoverflow.com/q/6041570

Answer (score 4):

There are two kinds of things template parameters can be: types and *compile-time constant expressions*. The contents of a function parameter is not a compile-time determinable value. And therefore, the compiler cannot instantiate a template based on it.

Remember: a template is a *type*. And types must be determinable at compile time.

You probably should pass the member pointer as an argument to the `Bind` function.

Answer (score 1):

I am not quite sure what you are trying to achieve?

If a `MemberFunctionPointer` is a variable, that the value of is unknown at compile time and, for example, may depend on some user behaviour - then it cannot be used as a template argument.

If, on the other hand, `MemberFunctionPointer` can be actually deduced at compile-time, you should pass it as a template argument, instead of a function parameter. Consider the following example:

(use `Bind` and `call` in the first case; in the second case, use `StaticBind` and `callStatic`)

```
#include <stdio.h>

class X {
  public:
    int x;
    void foo() {printf("foo\n");}
    void bar() {printf("bar\n");}
};

template <typename T>
class SomeClass {
  public:
    static void Bind(void (T::*MemberFunctionPointer)(), T *obj) {
      (obj->*MemberFunctionPointer)();
    }
    template <void (T::*MemberFunctionPointer)()>
    static void StaticBind(T *obj) {
      (obj->*MemberFunctionPointer)();
    }
};

template <class C>
static inline void call(void (C::*MemberFunctionPointer)(), C *obj) {
  SomeClass<C>::Bind(MemberFunctionPointer,obj);
}

template <class C, void (C::*MemberFunctionPointer)()>
static inline void callStatic(C *obj) {
  SomeClass<C>::template StaticBind<MemberFunctionPointer>(obj);
}

int main() {
  X obj;
  call<X>(&X::foo,&obj);
  callStatic<X,&X::bar>(&obj);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: I want it to be deduced at compile time, but I don't know how. So the second case fits better... only I try to provide a method "call" that does not take any template arguments.

Comment: In that case, you can actually use the first method, plus inline all functions. But then the Bind function, as shown in the example, has to take the member function pointer by parameter, not by template parameter. With optimisations turned on, it should boil down to a constant and you shoudl experience no runtime overhead. The template `<C>` parameter of the function `call` can be actually deduced from the passed parameters, so you can actually skip it in the call. I gave it there for clarity.

Answer (score 1):

Template parameters have to be known at compile-time. The contents of a pointer variable that is a function's parameter depends on how this function is invoked. This is not known at compile-time!

If you know this pointer at compile-time already, you can turn the function pointer runtime parameter into a template parameter:

```
template<class T_CLASS, void(T_CLASS::*MemFunPtr)()>
void Example(T_CLASS* InstancePointer) {...}
```

Here, MemFunPtr is a template parameter that is known at compile-time and can thus be resused as a template parameter for another function or class template...

Comment: Thanks, that's what I want to do. As I understand you there is no chance of passing the MemFunPtr as a normal parameter and avoid passing it as a template parameter to Example, right?

Answer (score 0):

`MemberFunctionPointer` is a variable not a *type (or compile-time constant)*, hence cannot be used, what you need is the real signature of that function, something like this may be better..

```
template<typename T_FUNC_PTR, class T_CLASS>
inline static void Example(T_FUNC_PTR fPtr, T_CLASS* InstancePointer)
{
  SomeClass<T_CLASS>::Bind<T_FUNC_PTR>(fPtr, InstancePointer);
}
```

i.e. let the compiler deduce the type of the function pointer (NOTE: you will have to propagate the pointer to the function too), to call

```
Example(&foo::bar, foo_inst);
```

This is untested and off the top of my head, so the syntax could be slightly off...

EDIT: here is a simpler example to demonstrate the concept:

```
#include <iostream>
struct foo
{
  void bar() { std::cout << "foo::bar()" << std::endl; }
};

template<typename T_FUNC_PTR, typename T_CLASS>
void exec(T_FUNC_PTR ptr, T_CLASS& inst)
{
  (inst.*ptr)();
}

int main(void)
{
  foo inst;
  exec(&foo::bar, inst);
}
```

Comment: Your first sentence suggests that only types can be used as template parameters. This is not true. The template system of C++ also accepts non-type parameters. But these have to be *compile-time* constants of either integral type or a pointer/reference to something with external linkage.

Comment: @sellibitze, really? I explicitly stated that the variable is a variable and not a type... I guess I'll be a bit more explicit...

Comment: Thanks for replying. As I described above, I want my member function pointer to be a non-type template argument. When passing it as one like in my call of "Bind" there is no problem - but I would like to have a easier to use wrapper function "Example" that does not take template parameters. Example should get the MemberFunctionPointer as parameter and pass it to "Bind" as non-type template parameter. It always points to the same function and I want to make the compiler know it at compile time. Is this possible?

Comment: @Micro, this is what my example is doing, when `exec` is called, I don't explicitly specify the types, the compiler works it out based on the arguments. In your code, you don't need the `Bind<T_FUNC_PTR>`, the compiler can work it out based on the passed in argument (`fPtr`)

Comment: @Nim, correct me if I'm wrong, but in your code exec I could not use ptr as a non-type template parameter which is what I want to do for the call of Bind. I don't want to pass the type of the function pointer but the function pointer itself as the argument.

Comment: @Micro, you cannot do that, your best bet is to pass the function pointer itself, and let the compiler determine the appropriate type in `Bind`.