# Using lua_error with LuaJIT skips stack object destructors?

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, lua, destructor, luajit

I've compiled LuaJIT with MSVC x64, which means that there should be full C++ exception interoperability, [according to the official LuaJIT website](http://luajit.org/extensions.html#exceptions).

One of the points states that "*Throwing Lua errors across C++ frames is safe. C++ destructors will be called.*"

I assumed that this means I can use *lua_error* in a C++ function and not worry about objects on the stack:

```
struct Test
{
    Test() {std::cout<<"Constructor"<<std::endl;}
    ~Test() {std::cout<<"Destructor"<<std::endl;}
};

int some_function(lua_State *l)
{
    Test t {};
    lua_pushstring(l,"error message");
    lua_error(l);
    return 0;
}
```

(The function is called from within a Lua-script)

However, the destructor is never called. So what does that point on the website actually mean? How can I use *lua_error* without having to worry about memory leaks?

According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4615890/2482983), the problem can be solved by compiling Lua as C++-code, but since I'm using LuaJIT, I'm not sure if that won't cause me any problems?

Comment: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSLTBW_2.3.0/com.ibm.zos.v2r3.cbclx01/cplr155.htm

Comment: Lua uses longjmp for errors and will therefore happily skip your destructors.  You could circumvent the issue by putting the error in a scope guard.

Comment: In that case the longjmp would occur in the destructor of the scope guard, which doesn't seem very safe.